# Problem with updating online users in database

Tags: php, laravel

I use laravel/ui composer package that installs login and register functionality in my site. I had to make online/offline functionality so I edited AuthenticatesUsers.php trait and login and logout functions in it in vendor folder so that when user is logged in it changes column 'online' in users table to 1. Now at myself it works fine, but when I push those files on git and someone else pulls them then they don't have that code from AuthenticatesUsers.php and the functionality doesn't work. Is there some way to implement that code in my own files so that when I push to git they are there, or some other way for them to stay on git? Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

AuthenticatesUsers.php

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

trait AuthenticatesUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Show the application's login form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    /**
     * Handle a login request to the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        if (method_exists($this, 'hasTooManyLoginAttempts') &&
            $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
            User::setOnlineStatus($user->id, 1);  // HERE IS CHANGE!!!

            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }

    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            $this->username() => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }

    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->guard()->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
        );
    }

    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    }

    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //
    }

    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ]);
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'email';
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
        User::setOnlineStatus($user->id, 0);  // HERE IS CHANGE!!!

        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect('/');
    }

    protected function loggedOut(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
}
```

User.php

```
public static function setOnlineStatus($user_id, $status)
{
    $user = User::getUser($user_id);
    $user->online = $status;
    $user->save();
}
```

Comment: **Never** edit files in the `vendor` folder, that will only cause you problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't edit your composer packages on your local environment. What you may do is; overwrite the methods that you edited on `AuthenticatesUsers` trait in your `AuthController`. Since these changes will be reflected on your Github changes(AuthController is not git ignored), your colleague will have those changes when they pull your branch.

Your `AuthController` will have the following method, not your local `vendor/AuthenticatesUsers`

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    if (method_exists($this, 'hasTooManyLoginAttempts') &&
        $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
        User::setOnlineStatus($user->id, 1);  // HERE IS CHANGE!!!

        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

- Another option may be writing your `AuthenticatesUsers` trait in your project and use it. You need to keep track of the changes when you upgrade your laravel dependency.
- If you think your changes fixing some bug etc, you may open a pull request in laravel github page and when it is merged you may use the updated one(it doesn't fit to your case, since you are `customizing` methods)
- Fork laravel project, make those changes and use this fork instead of the official one. This will require a lot of manual workload while upgrading.